# Get latest Amazon RDS snapshot using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'm trying to obtain the latest RDS Snapshot using the AWS SDK (Java, specifically). This has been asked and solved before using the AWS CLI ([How to find latest or most recent AWS RDS snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463085/how-to-find-latest-or-most-recent-aws-rds-snapshot))

The proposed solutions all involve the `--query` param which is conspicuously absent in the SDK:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots \
  --query="reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots, &SnapshotCreateTime))[0]"
```

Is there any way to do this using the SDK or do I have to get all of the paginated snapshots, gather the dates, and then sort and select the most recent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--query` parameter in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) merely **filters the output fields** that are returned by the command.

The `reverse()` and `sort_by` functionality is implemented locally within the AWS CLI using the [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) library. Your program that calls the SDK direcctly would need to perform such logic itself. This wouldn't be very difficult, since it would just involve sorting lists of values.